# SoundPool crashes app

Tags: java, android, crash, counter, soundpool

I'm kind of new to java, so bear with me if I've made a very stupid mistake. 
I am trying to play a sound when a button is clicked on a counter app using SoundPool, but 
the app crashes when either of the buttons are clicked.
No errors show up during compilation. 
Here's the code.

```
package com.example.c0unter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.media.AudioManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int Count=0;
    private SoundPool spool;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button ResetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ResetButton);
        Button CounterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CounterButton);
        final TextView CountText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CountText);


         ResetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Sound(R.raw.reset_button);
                Count=0;
                CountText.setText(" " + Count);

            }

        });




     CounterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
             Sound(R.raw.counter_button);
             Count++;
             CountText.setText(" " +Count);
         }
     });
    }

    public void Sound(int soundID){

          spool.load(this, soundID ,1);
          AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
          float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
          spool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    };

}
```

Comment: Will you paste the logcat output for the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spool` is `null`. When you call it here:

```
spool.load(this, soundID ,1);
```

You will get a `nullPointerException`. You need to initialise it first before you use it. For example:

```
spool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
```

I suggest you also have another look through some of the tutorials like [this](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/sound-pool-example-in-android-development/) one as there are some other errors in your code. You have to first load the sounds and get an ID back and then pass that ID to `play`. You cannot just pass `R.raw.reset_button` to `play`, it won't work.

Comment: I fixed the issues and managed to get the sound playing, but the sound stopped playing after I clicked the button  20 or so times. The app doesn't crash now. 
Any idea why?
@KenWolf

Comment: Great! I am not 100% sure as to the new error. If you are still experiencing problems I suggest you submit a new question with the updated code and relevant details.

Comment: Seems I was creating a new SoundPool everytime a button was clicked and it just ran out of memory I guess. Fixed it, it works fine now.
Thanks!